# Pros and cons of loading components in router actions VS before router initialization

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cordova, requirejs, ria

**What are the drawbacks/advantages of doing this:**

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery'), Backbone = require('backbone'), $content = $("#content");

    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "":                 "home",
            "employees/:id":    "employee"
        },

        home: function() {
            require(["app/views/Home"], function (HomeView) {
                var view = new HomeView({el: $content});
                view.render();
            });
        },

        employee: function(id) {
            require(["app/views/Employee", "app/models/Employee"], function (EmployeeView, Employee) {
                var employee = new Employee({id: id});
                employee.fetch({
                    success: function (data) {
                        var view = new EmployeeView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
   });
});
```

**Over this:**

*(pay attention to lines 4-6)*

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery'), Backbone = require('backbone'), $content = $("#content");

    var HomeView = require("app/views/Home"),
        EmployeeView = require("app/views/Employee"),
        Employee = require("app/models/Employee");

    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "":                 "home",
            "employees/:id":    "employee"
        },

        home: function() {
            var view = new HomeView({el: $content});
            view.render();
        },

        employee: function(id) {
            var employee = new Employee({id: id});
            employee.fetch({
                success: function (data) {
                    var view = new EmployeeView({model: data, el: $content});
                    view.render();
                }
            });
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 will load all dependencies into memory when the application starts (regardless of whether it is used or not); Option 1 will load the dependencies on the fly when the route is called and the modules are needed.

Option 1 seems better to me.